# Why my bundle not able to use background services?

Tags: osgi, jackrabbit, apache-felix, sling

I am working on a project in which I used **Adobe CQ5**.

In the mean while I have to use **background service** in my class i.e., **SlingRepository**.

For that I used Reference Annotation

```
@Reference
protected SlingRepository repository;
```

When I deploy this bundle in OSGI container, it does not able to use this service, it gives **null exception**.

Can you tell me please where I am wrong ?

I am totally stuck here.

Comment: Does your build use the maven-scr-plugin to process the @Reference annotation and to create the declarative services config?
If not that could be the reason, else I would check if the class that declares this dependency is really managed by the service 
component runtime or if your bundle has not been activated. What does your error.log tell you?

Comment: @Thomas I solved this problem , now my bundle use the background service. It shows error in the next step. Now I stuck in that. Anyways thanks to take time to understand my problem.

Comment: @Thomas Can we do a small chat please. If you have time?